# How to replace/update a key value inside a json array in golang?

Tags: json, go, range

I have a json array where it contains some flags as key and I have set the default values for those keys as false. this is my json array.

```
var flags = map[string]bool{
    "terminationFlag":  false,
    "transferFlag":   false,
    "jrCancelledFlag": false,
    "jrFilledFlag":  false,
}
```

On performing an operation in a for loop, i have to update 1 field in the above json array as true. During the next iteration, it has to update the 2nd field in the json array as true. After all the fields in the json array is set to true, I have to return the json array.

the code i tried:

```
  Keystrings := []string{"terminationReport - 2019-1","transferReport - 2019-1","jrCancelledReport - 2019-1","jrFilledReport - 2019-1"}
  fmt.Println("Keystrings ", Keystrings)

  for i,value := range Keystrings {     
    bytesread, err = stub.GetState(value)
    var result []string
    _ = json.Unmarshal(bytesread, &result)
    fmt.Println("result ", result)
    if result[0] == "yes"{
        fmt.Println("result in if ", result)
       flags[i] = true
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `i` in your code snippet?

Comment: There are a couple confusing things about your question. You refer to a `map[string]bool` and key-value pairs as a JSON array, but maps, if at all, might only represent JSON *objects*. See https://www.json.org/
There also isn't any actual JSON anywhere in your question, so I am not sure if I understand what is going on.

Comment: i refers to index variable in for loop like for i,value := range Keystrings { }

Comment: But there is no `i` in your loop range. Also, note that the contents of `Keystrings` don't map as keys of `flags` because they have extra year-month after the name. You should try to post a minimal code sample that actually runs, and try to separate the two steps (reading JSON from updating the `flags` map). Otherwise it's challenging to help you because we have to guess your intent

Comment: I am new to golang. if there is any errors in declaring a json array, kindly suggest me the changes. My requirement is ** I have to update the value of terminationFlag, transferredFlag, jrCancelledFlag, jrFilledFlag to "true" on iteration of for loop**. only 1 flag has to be updated during 1 iteration. then i have to return the complete json after updating all the flags. If any syntax errors please help me in doing the changes also.

Comment: Add two example lines of input data from your json file to the question please.  This will make it much easier to understand

Comment: @ Eli Bendersky the flags is an dynamic array that i have created to store the values as true. If there is any other way to store true in the respective flag and return those values, please help me on this. because i have no idea how to update and pass. and this is my full code

Comment: @Vorsprung I dont have any specific input data.  the values in the Keystrings [ ] is the Keys that i have already stored in my db. so getstate(value) will give me the value for that particular Key. In my case, the value obtained from db is "yes". If i get the result as "yes", I have to update 1 flag as true. Like wise i have to check the value for other Keys that i have in Keystrings and check whether the result obtained is "yes", If "yes", again set another flag to true.

Comment: Priyanka, I really want to help but you're making it super hard, I hope you see why. You should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve in detail, a few times, and try to map the advice to your question. I'm posting an answer with some general building blocks that will be useful for your question, hopefully that will help you get to the right solution. SO is unlikely to solve every last issue in the code for you and ultimately you'll have to practice and learn to debug your code and adjust samples you find to your concrete needs. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Since it's very hard to understand from the question what is being asked, here's a simple attempt at working with similar data as the question, in the hope that you can take the right parts from this sample and adapt them to your issue. Follow the comments in the code to understand what's going on.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

var jsonBlob = []byte(`["jrCancelledFlag", "yes"]`)

var flags = map[string]bool{
    "terminationFlag": false,
    "transferFlag":    false,
    "jrCancelledFlag": false,
    "jrFilledFlag":    false,
}

func main() {
    // Parse jsonBlob into a slice of strings
    var parsed []string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob, &parsed); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("JSON unmarshal: %s", err)
    }

    // Expect the slice to be of length 2, first item flag name, second item
    // yes/no.
    if len(parsed) != 2 {
        log.Fatalf("parsed len %d, expected 2", len(parsed))
    }

    // Assume parsed[0] actually appears in flags... otherwise more error checking
    // is needed.
    if parsed[1] == "yes" {
        flags[parsed[0]] = true
    }

    // Emit updated flags as json
    json, err := json.Marshal(flags)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("JSON marshal: %s", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(json))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved cleaning by using the JSON interface to define your own unmarshaller

https://medium.com/@nate510/dynamic-json-umarshalling-in-go-88095561d6a0

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

var jsonBlob = []byte(`["jrCancelledFlag", "yes"]`)

// Flags ...
type Flags struct {
    TerminationFlag bool `json:"terminationFlag,omitempty"`
    TransferFlag    bool `json:"transferFlag,omitempty"`
    JRCancelledFlag bool `json:"jrCancelledFlag,omitempty"`
    JRFilledFlag    bool `json:"jrFilledFlag,omitempty"`
}

// UnmarshalJSON satisfies the JSON unmarshaller interface
func (f *Flags) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var parsed []string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob, &parsed); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(parsed)%2 != 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("expected string to be evenly paired")
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(parsed); i++ {
        j := i + 1
        if j < len(parsed) {
            switch parsed[i] {
            case "terminationFlag":
                f.TerminationFlag = toBool(parsed[j])
            case "transferFlag":
                f.TransferFlag = toBool(parsed[j])
            case "jrCancelledFlag":
                f.JRCancelledFlag = toBool(parsed[j])
            case "jrFilledFlag":
                f.JRFilledFlag = toBool(parsed[j])
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func toBool(s string) bool {
    if s == "yes" {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func main() {

    var flags Flags
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob, &flags)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    b, _ := json.Marshal(flags)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```